# Inverse and multiplication of (symmetric, positive definite) Toeplitz matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{n\times k}$ be two Toeplitz matrices, with $A$ symmetric and positive definite.

I am searching for an elegant proof (or a counterexample) for the following two statements

1. $A^{-1}$ is symmetric and Toeplitz as well
2. $AB$ is Toeplitz

I played around with a few random numerical examples and it seems to hold. However, I was not able to get a simple proof and I was a bit reluctant to start digging in indices. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any invertible matrix $X$, we have $(X^{-1})^T=(X^T)^{-1}$. So, if $X$ is symmetric, $(X^{-1})^T=(X^T)^{-1}=X^{-1}$ and hence $X^{-1}$ is symmetric. Now your $A$ is symmetric and invertible. Hence its inverse is symmetric. This has nothing to do with the property that $A$ is Toeplitz.

The inverses or products of positive definite Toeplitz matrices are not Toeplitz in general. Examples:
\begin{align*}
&\begin{pmatrix}3&2&1\\2&3&2\\1&2&3\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=\frac18\begin{pmatrix}5&-4&1\\-4&8&-4\\1&-4&5\end{pmatrix},\\
&\begin{pmatrix}3&2&1\\2&3&2\\1&2&3\end{pmatrix}^2
=\begin{pmatrix}14&14&10\\14&17&14\\10&14&14\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
I am surprised to read that $A^{-1}$ and $AB$ are Toeplitz in all your random numerical examples.

Comment: Apparently, my choice of examples was not very good. Thanks a lot for your answer.